# If the supremum of absolute value of bounded linear functional is finite in a normed linear space $X$ then supremum of $\|x_\alpha\|$ is also finite.

Tags: normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

I was supposed to use the Principle of Uniform bounded to prove the following assertion:

If $\{x_\alpha\}$ be the set of elements in a normed linear space $X$ and

$\sup\limits_\alpha |f(x_α)| < \infty$ for any $f \in X^*$ (Topological Dual) then  $\sup\limits_\alpha \|x_α\| < \infty$

I don't have any clue to start this. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. These things would also apply to LaTeX, and you'll probably be using that at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a corallary of the Hanh Banach Theorem which says for every $x_\alpha\neq 0$, there exists a $f \in X^*$ such that $||f||=1$ and $f(x_\alpha)=||x_\alpha ||$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the family of functionals $\Lambda_\alpha\in X^{**}$ defined by $\Lambda_\alpha(f) := f(x_\alpha)$ for every $f\in X^*$.